# flyspell in terminal

Tags: flyspell

I'm trying to use flyspell from inside the terminal but when I run `flyspell-correct-word-before-point` I get the error `This command requires pop-up dialogs`. Is there a way to work around this issue? Am I just misconfigured? I don't believe I have any flyspell-specific configuration settings.

Answer (score 1):

EmacsWiki has the answer to this question on the [Fly Spell](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FlySpell) page:

> If you’d like to use Flyspell’s menu selection in the terminal, or just prefer to use popup.el over the graphical menu, stick this somewhere in your load path:

```
(defun flyspell-emacs-popup-textual (event poss word)
  "A textual flyspell popup menu."
  (require 'popup)
  (let* ((corrects (if flyspell-sort-corrections
                       (sort (car (cdr (cdr poss))) 'string<)
                     (car (cdr (cdr poss)))))
         (cor-menu (if (consp corrects)
                       (mapcar (lambda (correct)
                                 (list correct correct))
                               corrects)
                     '()))
         (affix (car (cdr (cdr (cdr poss)))))
         show-affix-info
         (base-menu  (let ((save (if (and (consp affix) show-affix-info)
                                     (list
                                      (list (concat "Save affix: " (car affix))
                                            'save)
                                      '("Accept (session)" session)
                                      '("Accept (buffer)" buffer))
                                   '(("Save word" save)
                                     ("Accept (session)" session)
                                     ("Accept (buffer)" buffer)))))
                       (if (consp cor-menu)
                           (append cor-menu (cons "" save))
                         save)))
         (menu (mapcar
                (lambda (arg) (if (consp arg) (car arg) arg))
                base-menu)))
    (cadr (assoc (popup-menu* menu :scroll-bar t) base-menu))))
```

> and put this in your init file:

```
(eval-after-load "flyspell"
  '(progn
     (fset 'flyspell-emacs-popup 'flyspell-emacs-popup-textual)))
```